# convert c# string[] to json

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have a method that returns a string[] back to a controller action and that action returns a **JsonAction** like so:

```
// GET: Locations/Get
[HttpGet]
public async Task<JsonResult> Get(string lotNumber)
{
    var result = await this.MakeApiCall("/locations?lotNumber=" + lotNumber);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

in my Javascript, if I do this:

```
core.get(locationsApi + "?lotNumber=" + core.getParameterByName("lotNumber"), function (response) {
    var r = JSON.parse(response);

    console.log(r);
});
```

I see a string that looks similar to this:

> > ["BA01A1","BA01A2","BA01A3"]

but, this seems to be a string because if I do this:

```
core.get(locationsApi + "?lotNumber=" + core.getParameterByName("lotNumber"), function (response) {
    var r = JSON.parse(response);
    var r = JSON.parse(r);

    console.log(r);
});
```

It actually returns an array....
How can I get my action to return the array in the beginning or at the very least return something that I only have to parse once?

Comment: what is `core`? the problem is with that library. and what is a `result`?

Comment: What does MakeApiCall() return? Is it a json string? If so, it's being double serialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the type of `var result =` returned from `MakeApiCall` is of type `string` but contains `["BA01A1","BA01A2","BA01A3"]` which is essentially serialized JSON.

You can determine this by mousing over `var` and seeing what the type is, and also using a debugger to see what the actual value is returned from the API call.

When you then return that serialized JSON with `Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` the string is getting serialized into yet another JSON representation.

Essentially it's been double serialized.

When you use this, client side the result.length == 3, the expected length of the array.

```
    public ActionResult GetAnswer(string question)
    {               
        var answer = @"[""BA01A1"",""BA01A2"",""BA01A3""]";
        return Content(answer, "text/javascript");
    }
    // javascript result.length returns 3
```

When instead you use the Json helper, you get a string with 28 characters instead, because the Json helper assumes you are passing an object that should be serialized, but the problem is, you already have a an array that's represented as a serialized string:

```
    public ActionResult GetAnswer(string question)
    {                   
        var answer = @"[""BA01A1"",""BA01A2"",""BA01A3""]";
        return Json(answer);            
    }
    // javascript result.length returns 28
```

This fiddle demonstrates this.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NCAPkh

**TLDR** In your case `var result` is likely already a string representation of a JSON serialized object, and passing it to the `Json(` helper then serializes it again.  Hence client side you must deserialize twice.

You have two options, either deserialize the string from the API call into a C# object list, then pass that object list to `return Json(someObject...` or return it as Content with type JSON(demonstrated above).